# Relationship between the roots of derivatives and their functions

Tags: calculus, derivatives, roots

Given that $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$, I know that "between the zeroes of $f$, there is a zero of $f'$.

But given that $f'$ has $k$ roots, then is it true that $f$ has at most $k+1$ roots.

Answer (score 3):

yes, suppose that $f$ has $k+2$ distinct roots $x_1<x_2...<x_{k+2}$ there exists a root $y_i$ of $f'$ between $x_i$ and $x_{i+1}$ so there is $y_1<y_2..<y_{k+1}$ roots, contradiction.

Comment: What if $f$ does not have distinct roots though? What if roots are complex?